# vcpkg: how to downgrade the python3 package

Tags: vcpkg

It installed the latest version. I want it to match the specific version that I use. How can I downgrade it (e.g. from 3.10 to 3.7)? The update should include dependencies such as boost.

---

Currently, I'm manually specifying:

```
set(Python_LIBRARY "c:/python37/libs/python37.lib")
set(Python_INCLUDE_DIR "c:/python37/include/")
```

which won't influence the dependent packages.

---

EDIT Following Augustin Popa's answer.

In my project directory (where the cmakefile is) I created vcpkg.json

```
{
    "name": "confstruct",
    "version-string": "1.0.0",
    "builtin-baseline": "98f8d00e89fb6a8019c2045cfa1edbe9d92d3405",
    "overrides": [
        { "name": "python3", "version": "3.7.4" }
    ],
    "dependencies": [
        { "name": "python3" }
    ]
}
```

confstruct is from `project( confstruct )` in the cmakefile.
version-string is just something I made up.
builtin-baseline is something that vcpkg complained was missing and recommended for me. Not sure if it's the git version of vcpkg, why I should care about it, and if I can simply put "recent" or something.

In my cmakefile, I have:

```
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Development REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Python:")
message(STATUS "    Python_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "    Python_LIBRARIES: ${Python_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "    Python_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Python_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
```

With python 3.10, cmake runs fine. With the override, I see that it installs python37.lib, which is good, but cmake fails with:

```
CMake Error at C:/prog/cmake-gui/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Development Development.Module
  Development.Embed) (found version "2.7")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/prog/cmake-gui/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/prog/cmake-gui/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython.cmake:561 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/prj-external-libs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:824 (_find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)
```

On the subject, if it's going to find python37_d.lib, can I tell it not to? Reason:

[cmake: set python cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016266/cmake-set-python-cleanly)

Answer (score 0):

In this post I will use the term "ports". For your purposes, a "port" is a "package" in vcpkg. I am not using the term "package" because there is a second type of package in vcpkg called an artifact, which works very differently.

In short, if you want to control port versions with vcpkg, it's best to use a manifest file (vcpkg.json) and the *version>=* or *overrides* feature to set the desired version. Don't worry about upstream dependencies of python3, vcpkg will still resolve these automatically as usual and you don't need to list them in vcpkg.json. There are other ways to do port versioning, but this is the cleanest solution. See the documentation on these features for more information (including examples):

1. https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/manifests.html
2. https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/versioning.htm

**Example vcpkg.json file with a version override**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version-semver": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": [
    { "name": "zlib", "version>=": "1.2.11#9" },
    "fmt"
  ],
  "builtin-baseline":"3426db05b996481ca31e95fff3734cf23e0f51bc",
  "overrides": [
    { "name": "fmt", "version": "6.0.0" }
  ]
}
```

If you have more time, it's worth familiarizing yourself with how versioning works in vcpkg because there is a reason it's designed differently than other package managers (especially compared to other programming languages).

**How versioning works in vcpkg**

*Background:* A catalog of ports is called a *registry*. A registry is really just a git repo. Since it's git, you can reference a particular point in the history of the repo using a git commit ID. vcpkg refers to such an ID as a *baseline*. You can designate a particular registry repo and baseline for your project to use in vcpkg.json. Once that is set, all ports are installed at the versions listed at that baseline in the registry. When you don't use a vcpkg.json or a baseline, you're just getting whatever is most recent in the repo. This is why you're currently getting only the latest version.

Once you have a baseline set up in a vcpkg.json, you can add additional versioning constraints:

1. **version>=**. You can use version>= to impose a soft requirement for a port version. Typically, this will be the very version you listed, though it is possible for vcpkg to choose a slightly higher version if it detects that the lower one would not build. All vcpkg dependencies in the public registry are tested against each other, so any time a new version of a dependency is introduced, it will only be allowed into the registry if it builds with other ports that depend on it or that it depends on. So by setting `{ "name": "python3", "version>=": "3.7" }`, you are telling vcpkg "*Please give me this version of python3 (which should be greater than what is in the baseline as well), but if that doesn't work, give me the next highest version*". In general, it is better for future compatibility to use baselines and version>= over overrides. However, if you have a simple project or know your port version compatibility story well, read on...
2. **Overrides**. This feature lets you hard-code your port version to a specific number. This will ignore your baseline completely and will always give you what you ask, whether that might break your build or not. When you use an override, you have full control, but vcpkg also can't help you if the version you requested isn't compatible with another port that depends on or is depended by python3. Example: `"overrides": [{ "name": "python3", version": "3.7" }]`

**Why versioning works this way in vcpkg**

In C++, when you make changes to your build (e.g. version of dependencies, compiler, compiler version, target architecture, target OS, certain compiler flags, ...), you are changing the ABI structure of your code. When you have multiple dependencies that each have their own upstream dependencies, your build fails if it violates ABI boundaries. In particular it will fail if two or more dependencies require a third dependency C, but not necessarily the same version of C. vcpkg gets around this by structuring the port registry (at each point in time/baseline) so that all dependency versions are compatible with all other dependencies at their respective versions. So no matter which dependencies you install at a particular baseline, they should "just work". At least for the target platforms x architectures vcpkg tests against :). And this is the reason why we recommend using baselines and version>= as much as possible for complex projects and long-term maintenance considerations, but of course you are welcome to use overrides instead if that's easier for you.

**Disclaimer:** I work on the vcpkg tool.

Comment: Thanks. You are missing an "l" in the second link. Please see my edit.